# React Native OnEndReached Starts On Load

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

So basically it just seems that React Native is buggy and problematic tool. It seems this bug still exists: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16067 .My Question is does anybody here know is this maybe solved recently? So when I use onendreached in my flatlist, it starts right when screen loads and not when end is reached. I tried ALL the solutions from all other similar questions on stackoverflow. I tried some momentum thing and many many others. this is my code:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FlatList
            style={{ marginHorizontal: 0, marginVertical: 6, }}
            data={this.state.post}
            renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderPost(item)}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter()}
            onEndReached={console.log("DOESNT WORK PROPERLY")}
          
          ></FlatList>
        </SafeAreaView>
```

So just when i refresh the screen or start the app text "DOESNT WORK PROPERLY" is activated right away, and not even just once but but always 3 or 4 times. Rn is broken. I tried some patches, i tried sooooo many different combinations

Comment: i think i should just use some button in the footer cause this isnt working for days.

Comment: Its because one will fire immediately and one will not due to scoping with the ES6 arrow syntax. I would definitely research https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions to understand why that worked in the unanswerable question that you answered yourself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got it. I didnt see this answer in any of the related questions anywhere online. Its incredibly simple, I just changed `onEndReached={console.log("DOESNT WORK PROPERLY")}` to this next line:   `onEndReached={() => console.log("yo")}`